# controlling file size based on threshold

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Can we control file size in Spark given its distributed processing capability? I have a simple workflow that generates data ranging 1GB to 15GB data to s3 on daily run. I need to create separate files if size exceeds 3 GB ie. a single file can have data upto 3GB.

For ex: if the pipeline generates 7GB data, I need to create 3 files as below.

- file 1 having 3GB or less
- file 2 having 3GB or less
- file 3 having 1GB

Can this be achievable in Spark?

Comment: What is your output format ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: You can limit the number of **rows** (not bytes) written per file regardless of the underlying format, see `spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile` in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: @Steven my output format is json spark.write.json<> . I have tried coalesce/repartition, but I dont know how to limit on file size.

Comment: thanks @mazaneicha similar to number of rows, do we have any parameter for file size ? if not, Im thinking getting line size multiplies by rows to arrive at apprx size. Given spark does serialization,deserialization, different files types on input /output, how do we calculate line size?

Comment: I guess it'd be easier to get via experiment than calculations -- set maxRecords to a 100-1000-10000 and take average size of the written files. Then adjust to taste :)